# Settings LOCALE on Raspberry Pi3

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, perl, locale

I'm using raspberry for years and Linux for many more... Trying to installing Docker in my rpi I get an error, it is probably related to the LOCALE installation. The problem is this:

```
apt-listchanges: Can't set locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct!
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

I have already tried a lot of guides but the problem persists.

Any help?

Comment: It seems that [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599808/cannot-set-lc-ctype-to-default-locale-no-such-file-or-directory) have solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

Edit your `/etc/locale.gen` then uncomment the following line:

```
en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

Run:

```
sudo locale-gen en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8
sudo update-locale en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_GB.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
```

Verify it;

```
locale
```

You may get:

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
```

And Done !!!

Answer (score 1):

See the solution posted here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269159/problem-of-cant-set-locale-make-sure-lc-and-lang-are-correct

short answer:
Run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` as root, select the locales you want in the list (with your settings, you need en_GB and en_US.UTF-8 — I recommend selecting en_US and en_GB.UTF-8 as well) then press .